# Play video without interrupting/stopping the background audio in Android

Tags: android, audio, video

How can we play a video without an audio, and without interrupting the background music? That is, the audio being played by a background app like the Music app or Soundcloud shouldn't stop.

If you check the Facebook app, the auto-play video feature doesn't interrupt/stop the background music. I want similar behaviour in my application.

Answer (score 1):

try setAudioFocusRequest(AUDIOFOCUS_NONE)on your video view

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ExoPlayer you can do this :

```
SimpleExoPlayer simpleExoPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
// just add below line to stop background music 
simpleExoPlayer.setAudioAttributes(simpleExoPlayer.getAudioAttributes(), /* 
handleAudioFocus= */ true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code work fine without any issue

```
 private void gainFocus( AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener focusChangeListener){
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        // Request audio focus for playback

        int result = am.requestAudioFocus(focusChangeListener,
                // Use the music stream.
                AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                // Request permanent focus.
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);


        if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            // other app had stopped playing song now , so u can do u stuff now .
        }
    }
```

and register listener of audio focus in onCreate() method of activity and then call gainfocus() method depend on condition state of audio focus

```
  void registerAudioFocus(){
        if(mMediaPlayer!=null){

            /*code for stop other application sound while app video playing*/
            focusChangeListener =
                    new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
                        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                            AudioManager am =(AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                            switch (focusChange) {

                                case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
                                    // Lower the volume while ducking.
                                    if(mMediaPlayer!=null)
                                        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f, 0.2f);
                                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    break;
                                case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) :
                                    pause();
                                    //  Toast.makeText(getContext(),"AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    break;

                                case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) :

                                        if(mMediaPlayerValid) {
                                            gainFocus(this);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ((AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE)).abandonAudioFocus(focusChangeListener);
                                        }

                                    break;

                                case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) :
                                    // Return the volume to normal and resume if paused.
                                      //  Toast.makeText(getContext(),"AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    if(mMediaPlayer!=null) {
                                        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1f, 1f);
                                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                                    }

                                        gainFocus(this);


                                    break;
                                default: break;
                            }
                        }
                    };

            gainFocus(focusChangeListener);
        }
    }
```

please this will work fine for me

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing you're using VideoView to display the video. Try to use SurfaceView instead. I've tried both, and in fact VideoView stops any third party music app and the SurfaceView does not.